# Convert data from image picker intent into bitmap (Kotlin)?

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap

I'm currently trying to save whatever image the user picks into a room database, and it looks like the only way to do this is to first save it as a bitmap. However, I'm not sure how I would do this.

This is the code that I have right now: it lets the user pick an image and displays it in an imageview after. However, I don't know how I could convert my `data?.data` into a bitmap.

I apologize if this wasn't a very good question, I'm very  new to dealing with images and image types in android apps. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```kotlin
// Opens gallery when image button clicked, gets image
        view.image_et.setOnClickListener {
            readStorageTask()
            //Intent to pick image
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
            intent.type = "image/*"
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1001)
        }

// Handle result of picked image
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1001) {
            preview_image.setImageURI(data?.data)
        }
    }
```

I've seen some StackOverflow questions similar to mine dealing with the same issue in Java, but the ones that I've tried just haven't worked for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: No need to create bitmap. You can use this class https://gist.github.com/jaisoni/4d4e20409849dd3cfa12ee15895124a6  for finding actual path of image and use Picasso or other library for showing preview from actual path

Comment: @JaiprakashSoni Thanks for your comment! I've seen some things like this before, but I want the image to stay in my app even when the actual image is deleted from the user's phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a file in cache directory, then create bitmap

```
    if (data != null && data.data != null) {
        val uri = data.data!!
        val inputStream = requireContext().contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
        val cursor = requireContext().contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)
        cursor?.use { c ->
          val nameIndex = c.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
          if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            val name = c.getString(nameIndex)
            inputStream?.let { inputStream ->
               // create same file with same name
               val file = File(requireContext().cacheDir, name)
               val os = file.outputStream()
                os.use {
                 inputStream.copyTo(it)
                 }
                val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.absolutePath)
              }
            }
         }               
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Open an input stream for the obtained uri and then use BitmapFactory.decodeStream().

In Java:

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

That's all.